# AngularJS Manga Reading Website

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We have a manga reading website and we are trying to rebuild it with AngularJS [Our Current Website with PHP](http://mangayurdu.com/). We had a lot of progress but stuck at here. At the main page, Naruto button "649" like current one. When we click this it has to load Naruto Chapter 649's images. But its loads blank page. Here is our code:

Our JSON:

```
[
{
"seri": "Bleach",
"random": [
    {
        "klasor": "787",
        "yol": [
            "path/to/1.jpg",
            "path/to/2.jpg",
            "path/to/3.jpg"
        ]
    },
    {
        "klasor": "788",
        "yol": [
            "path/to/1.jpg",
            "path/to/2.jpg",
            "path/to/3.jpg"
        ]
    }
]
},
{
"seri": "Naruto",
"random": [
    {
        "klasor": "332",
        "yol": [
            "path/to/1.jpg",
            "path/to/2.jpg",
            "path/to/3.jpg"
        ]
    },
    {
        "klasor": "333",
        "yol": [
            "path/to/1.jpg",
            "path/to/2.jpg",
            "path/to/3.jpg"
        ]
    }
]
}
]
```

Related App.js part:

```
$stateProvider
.state('oku', {
url: "/oku/:name/:id",
views: {
"viewC": { templateUrl: "oku.html",
            controller: "nbgCtrl",},
},
})
.factory('MangaService', function($http) {
var mService = {};
var url = '/uzak/remote1.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
mService.allMangas = $http.get(url);
// retrieve your full JSON into mService.allMangas here
// you could additionally track states like loading/error

mService.getMangaSeri = function(name) {
    return mService.allMangas.filter(function (el) {
        return el.seri == name;
    })[0];
}

mService.getMangaSeriKlasor = function(name, num) {
    var seri = mService.getMangaSeri(name);
    return seri.random.filter(function (el) {
        return el.klasor == num;
    })[0];
}

return mService;
})

.controller('nbgCtrl', function($scope, MangaService) {
MangaService.allMangas.success(function(verHemen){
   $scope.bilgiler = verHemen;  
})
})
```

Naruto 649 button, link is like "oku/Naruto/649", loads the oku.html and "manga" is coming from another JSON.

```
<a ui-sref="oku({id:manga.last, name:manga.name})" class="waves-effect waves-light btn">{{manga.last}}</a>
```

Related oku.html part, oku.html is where is images are displaying:

```
<div class="col s8 offset-s2" ng-repeat="bilgi in bilgiler.random">
<img ng-repeat="mypath in bilgi.yol" ng-src="http://localhost/{{mypath}}">
</div>
```

So our problem is just how do we display that images using angularJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `{{bilgi.yol}}` would actually be an array, and you are using that in your ng-src attribute.

Not exactly sure what you want to achieve, but maybe something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="bilgi in bilgiler.random">
    <img ng-repeat="mypath in bilgi.yol" ng-src="http://localhost/{{mypath}}">
</div>
```

That would display all images referenced in the respective bilgi.yol array.

What you are probably after is filtering your JSON by "seri" first, then filter the "random" from that result by "klasor", and then you have the manga chapter you want to display. Say you store this in myManga, you could simply do this:

```
<img ng-repeat="myPath in myManga.yol" ng-src="http://localhost/{{myPath}}">
```

As for working with the full JSON, while it is a waste of bandwidth, you could fetch it once in a service, and use it like this:

```
.factory('MangaService', function($http) {
    var mService = {};
    mService.allMangas = [];
    // retrieve your full JSON into mService.allMangas here
    // you could additionally track states like loading/error

    mService.getMangaSeri = function(name) {
        return mService.allMangas.filter(function (el) {
            return el.seri == name;
        })[0];
    }

    mService.getMangaSeriKlasor = function(name, num) {
        var seri = mService.getMangaSeri(name);
        return seri.random.filter(function (el) {
            return el.klasor == num;
        })[0];
    }

    return mService;
})
```

You can use this service in your controllers, and request the specific manga series and chapter by using the lookup functions.

For what it's worth, I'd personally go with a more specific php api that allows for more fine-grained requests.

Comment: That didn't work. I think problem is filter part of my code. `return $filter('filter')(res.data, {klasor: $stateParams.id}, true)[0];`

Comment: Can you add code for NBG to your question? I'm afraid I'm still struggling to get the full picture, apart from the obvious part in the answer above.

Comment: I added it. Its a factory that getting the JSON data.

Comment: Is it possible your filter is just returning nothing? Assuming that NBG does call the URL for the full JSON you posted above, filtering that data by "klasor" would indeed return empty, since you did basically try to look for a chapter in your top-level list of mangas. You'd want to look for the correct manga object by filtering for "seri" first, and then on that result look for the chapter by filtering on "klasor".

Comment: Yes. Someone from some other forum sad that too. Filter returning nothing. So what do I suppose to do now? Change my Mysql tables? Or how exactly my JSON data should look like? So I can change mysql to that way.

Comment: I'd not touch the mysql tables, if you can get the JSON you have above, then those must be fine. In fact, you could work with the full JSON data you have above, if you are not concerned with bandwidth. I'll update answer in a second with a crude example...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91432/discussion-between-nasuh-and-bgse).